# Yii2: Load modal form and submit data via Ajax without redirecting to view

Tags: ajax, yii2, modal-dialog

I have two models in my Yii2 project. One model: `ApartmentBuilding` depends on another model: `Caretaker` via a relationship. Assuming I am creating an `ApartmentModel` via a form whereby I select the `caretaker` from a dynamic dropdown. I then realize that the caretaker I need is not added yet to the database, hence, I have to add the details of the caretaker from the `ApartmentBuilding` model form then proceed filling in the details of the `ApartmentBulding` form. That is the usecase of my problem.

So far, I have managed to launch the `Caretaker` model form via a modal from the `ApartmentBulding` form. On submitting the details of the `Caretaker` model form, the site redirects to the view of the `CaretakerController`. However, what I need is to be able to get the dropdown form refresh with the new details of the caretaker that I just added via a modal, and be able to proceed with the filling of the rest of the form.

Any help in cracking this will be appreciated.

Here are my codes so far:

ApartmentBuilding _form.php

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use kartik\widgets\ActiveForm;
use app\models\Landlord;
use app\models\Caretaker;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use yii\bootstrap\Button;
use yii\helpers\Url;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model app\models\ApartmentBuilding */
/* @var $form yii\widgets\ActiveForm */
?>

<div class="apartment-building-form">

    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
        'type' => ActiveForm::TYPE_HORIZONTAL,
        'formConfig' => ['labelSpan' => 3, 'deviceSize' => ActiveForm::SIZE_TINY],
    ]); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'apartment_name')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'landlord_id')->dropDownList(ArrayHelper::map(Landlord::find()->select(['landlord_id', 'first_name', 'last_name'])->all(), 'landlord_id', 'displayName'),['class' => 'form-control inline-block', 'prompt'=>'Select Landlord']) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'physical_address')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'plot_number')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'address')->widget(\kalyabin\maplocation\SelectMapLocationWidget::className(), [
        'attributeLatitude' => 'latitude',
        'attributeLongitude' => 'longitude',
        'googleMapApiKey' => 'YOUR_API_KEY_HERE',
    ]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'number_of_floors')->textInput() ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'apartment_desc')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <div class="form-group kv-fieldset-inline">
        <?= Html::activeLabel($model, 'caretaker_id', ['label'=>'Caretaker', 'class'=>'col-sm-3 control-label']) ?>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <?= $form->field($model, 'caretaker_id',['showLabels'=>false])->dropDownList(ArrayHelper::map(Caretaker::find()->select(['caretaker_id', 'first_name', 'last_name'])->all(), 'caretaker_id', 'displayName'),['class' => 'form-control inline-block', 'prompt'=>'Select Caretaker']) ?>
        </div>  
        <div class="col-sm-1">
            <?= Html::button('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>', ['value'=>Url::to(['caretaker/new']), 'title' => 'Create New Caretaker', 'class' => 'btn btn-success showModalButton']) ?>
        </div>
    </div>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'other_apt_details')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9">
        <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
        <?= Html::resetButton('Reset', ['class' => 'btn btn-default']) ?>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

</div>
```

Caretaker _form.php

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use kartik\widgets\ActiveForm;
use kartik\widgets\DatePicker;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model app\models\Caretaker */
/* @var $form yii\widgets\ActiveForm */
?>

<div class="caretaker-form">

    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
        'type' => ActiveForm::TYPE_HORIZONTAL,
        'formConfig' => ['labelSpan' => 3, 'deviceSize' => ActiveForm::SIZE_TINY],
    ]); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'first_name')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'last_name')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'sex')->dropDownList(['Male' => 'Male', 'Female' => 'Female'],['prompt'=>'Select Sex']) ?> 

    <?= $form->field($model, 'date_of_birth')->widget(DatePicker::classname(), ['options' => ['placeholder' => 'Enter birth date ...'], 'pluginOptions' => ['autoclose'=>true, 'format' => 'yyyy-mm-dd']]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'address')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'mobile')->widget(\yii\widgets\MaskedInput::className(), ['mask' => '254999999999',]) ?>

    <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9">
        <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
        <?= Html::resetButton('Reset', ['class' => 'btn btn-default']) ?>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

</div>
```

CaretakerController actionNew()

```
public function actionNew()
{
    $model = new Caretaker();
    $model->company_id = Yii::$app->user->identity->company_id;

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return $this->renderAjax('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Modal Handler:

```
<?php
yii\bootstrap\Modal::begin([
    'headerOptions' => ['id' => 'modalHeader'],
    'id' => 'modal',
    'size' => 'modal-lg',
    //keeps from closing modal with esc key or by clicking out of the modal.
    // user must click cancel or X to close
    'clientOptions' => ['backdrop' => 'static', 'keyboard' => FALSE]
]);
echo '<div id="modalContent"><div style="text-align:center"><?= Html::img("@web/img/loading.gif");?></div></div>';
yii\bootstrap\Modal::end();
?>
```

modal-popup.js

```
$(function(){
    //get the click of modal button to create / update item
    //we get the button by class not by ID because you can only have one id on a page and you can
    //have multiple classes therefore you can have multiple open modal buttons on a page all with or without
    //the same link.
//we use on so the dom element can be called again if they are nested, otherwise when we load the content once it kills the dom element and wont let you load another modal on click without a page refresh
      $(document).on('click', '.showModalButton', function(){
         //check if the modal is open. if it's open just reload content not whole modal
        //also this allows you to nest buttons inside of modals to reload the content it is in
        //the if else are intentionally separated instead of put into a function to get the 
        //button since it is using a class not an #id so there are many of them and we need
        //to ensure we get the right button and content. 
        // if ($('#modal').data('bs.modal').isShown) 
        if ($("#modal").data('modal') && $("#modal").data('modal').isShown){
            $('#modal').find('#modalContent')
                    .load($(this).attr('value'));
            //dynamically set the header for the modal
            document.getElementById('modalHeader').innerHTML = '<h4>' + $(this).attr('title') + '</h4>';
        } else {
            //if modal isn't open; open it and load content
            $('#modal').modal('show')
                    .find('#modalContent')
                    .load($(this).attr('value'));
             //dynamiclly set the header for the modal
            document.getElementById('modalHeader').innerHTML = '<h4>' + $(this).attr('title') + '</h4>';
        }
    });
});

$(function(){
//load the current page with the conten indicated by 'value' attribute for a given button.
   $(document).on('click', '.loadMainContent', function(){
            $('#main-content').load($(this).attr('value'));
    });
});
```

**Note**
The `modal handler code` and the `modal-popup.js` are reused by several other modals such as view and create forms. The code for the modal handler is in the `main.php` of the layouts folder.

Comment: No one can assist me with this question?

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to solve the problem by doing the following (More thoughts on the same still welcome, I know there could be more perfect way of doing this):

I added the following `Javascript` code to the caretaker _form.php

```
<?php
$this->registerJs("$('#createcaretaker').click(function() {
    var firstName = $('#caretaker-first_name').val();
    var lastName = $('#caretaker-last_name').val();
    var sex = $('#caretaker-sex').val();
    var dOB = $('#caretaker-date_of_birth').val();
    var address = $('#caretaker-address').val();
    var mobile = $('#caretaker-mobile').val();
    $('#modal').modal('hide');
    $.get('new?firstName='+firstName+'&lastName='+lastName+'&sex='+sex+'&dOB='+dOB+'&address='+address+'&mobile='+mobile, function(success){
        $('.refreshcaretaker').html(success);
    });
});");
?>
```

Then, the submit button on the same form, I changed it to:

```
<button id="createcaretaker" type="button" class="btn btn-success">Create</button>
```

Hence, the button id is able to trigger the `Javascript` code above to send data to the server side.

I then created a controller action in the `ApartmentBuilding` controller to handle the data entry as follows:

```
public function actionNew($firstName, $lastName, $sex, $dOB, $address, $mobile)
{
    $model = new Caretaker();
    $model->company_id = Yii::$app->user->identity->company_id;

    if ($firstName != '0' && $lastName != '0' && $sex != '0' && $dOB != '0' && $address != '0' && $mobile != '0') {
        $model->first_name = $firstName;
        $model->last_name = $lastName;
        $model->sex = $sex;
        $model->date_of_birth = $dOB;
        $model->address = $address;
        $model->mobile = $mobile;
        $model->save();

        $caretakers = Caretaker::find()->all();
        foreach ($caretakers as $caretaker) {
            echo '<option value="'.$caretaker->caretaker_id.'">'.$caretaker->displayName.'</option>';
        }
    } else {
        return $this->renderAjax('caretaker_create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Having done that, I changed the dropdown entry of the parent form to be able to refresh its values via ajax upon submitting the modal form to create the caretaker model as follows:

```
<?= $form->field($model, '[{$i}]caretaker_id',['showLabels'=>false])->dropDownList(ArrayHelper::map(Caretaker::find()->select(['caretaker_id', 'first_name', 'last_name'])->all(), 'caretaker_id', 'displayName'),['class' => 'form-control inline-block refreshcaretaker', 'prompt'=>'Select Caretaker']) ?>
```

Note the `refreshcaretaker` class that is triggered by the `Javascript` code above when the modal is submitted.

The following [link](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/806/render-form-in-popup-via-ajax-create-and-update-with-ajax-validation-also-load-any-page-via-ajax-yii-2-0-2-3) talks more about using modal forms in Yii2.

Comment: I still have a problem however with closing the modal form after submitting the data from the modal form. Anyone with help on this? Using the above `Javascript` code?

Comment: I have taken care of this also by adding `$('#modal').modal('hide');`. The answer has been edited to reflect that.